# Give button the appearance that it has been activated

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, button, buttongroup

Hi im using bootstrap 4 , i have this buttons grup and i need to keep each button active when user clicks to it.. Right now if i click to one button it will give it the appearance that it has been activated, but when clicking anywhere in the screen this appearance dissapears...  how can i achive this? thanks!

```
 <div class="btn-group btn-group-sm btn-responsive " role="group" >
                    <button (click)="test('tx1')"  type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-responsive"  >Tx1</button>
                    <button (click)="test('tx2')" type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-responsive " >Tx2</button>
                    <button (click)="test('tx3')" type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-responsive ">Tx3</button>
                    <button (click)="test('tx4')" type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-responsive ">Tx4</button>
                    <button (click)="test('rx1')" type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-responsive ">Rx1</button>
                    <button (click)="test('rx2')" type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-responsive ">Rx2</button>
                    <button (click)="test('obst')" type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-responsive ">Obstaculo</button>
                  </div>
```

Comment: Which language is this? `(click)="test('tx3')"`

Comment: @PraveenKumar im suing angular 2

Comment: That's funny when you read it literally. You are ***suing*** something big. You must be a great person! 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to toggle an `active` CSS class `onclick` of each button element. The `.active` or whatever name you choose will have the styling you need. Do you use some JS framework ? So I can paste an example snippet.

In Angular it would be

.html

```
<button (click)="test('tx1')" [class.active]="activeButtonName === 'tx1'"  type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-responsive"  >Tx1</button>

<button (click)="test('tx2')" [class.active]="activeButtonName === 'tx2'"  type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-responsive"  >Tx2</button>
```

.scss

```
 .active {
     // your styles go here
    }
```

And in each button you set it like this .ts file

```
public activeButtonName: string = ''

test(buttonName: string): void {
 this.activeButtonName = buttonName;
}
```

Comment: im using angular 2 as a framework..please if u cand addapt your exampe to it , i will appreciate !

Comment: i updated it. it's quite easy what you are trying to achieve. perhaps some more studying in angular docs would help. if you have any troubles/issues with the code, please feel free to share.